# How to construct a stacked barchart

Tags: plotting

UPDATED to clearify

I want to construct a stacked barchart from a list with three elements:

```
list = Table[{i, x, y}, {i, 10}]
```

where x has a value between 0 and 100, and y has a value between 0 and 100 so it looks like this:

```
llist = {{1, 6, 611}, {2, 57, 732}, {3, 5, 526}, {4, 91, 72}, {5, 45, 
583}, {6, 98, 552}, {7, 16, 981}, {8, 54, 439}, {9, 80, 804}, {10,
 9, 633}};
```

I want to stack y based on brackets of x (eg. brackets of size 10). Based on the list above this gives the following brackets.

- Bracket `0 - 10` consists of $y$ value (s) `611, 526, 633`
- Bracket `10 - 20` consists of $y$ value (s) `981`
- Bracket `20 - 30` consists of $y$ value (s) empty
- Bracket `30 - 40` consists of $y$ value (s) empty
- Bracket `40 - 50` consists of $y$ value (s) `583`
- Bracket `50 - 60` consists of $y$ value (s) `732, 439`
- Bracket `70 - 80` consists of $y$ value (s) empty
- Bracket `80 - 90` consists of $y$ value (s) `804`
- Bracket `90 - 100` consists of $y$ value (s) `72, 552`

The result should look something like this:

[image]

Some context: this is a plot I want to make to show how much influence is exerted (y values) on certain policy positions (x values). The first elements are actors. So Actor 1 exerts 611 influence on policy position 6 (first bracket 0-10). For each bracket I want to visually see how much influence is exerted by the actors and how this looked stacked

Comment: No I don't want stacked counts but I want to stack the values themselves (e.g. for the first bracket 611, 526 and 633 stacked on top of each other). Some context: this is a plot I want to make to show how much influence is exerted (y values) on certain policy positions (x values). The first elements are actors. So Actor 1 exerts 611 influence on policy position 6 (first bracket 0-10). For each bracket I want to visually see how much influence is exerted by the actors and how this looked stacked.

Comment: My suggestion: `Module[{data, brackets},
 data = GatherBy[Append[#, #[[2]]/10 // IntegerPart] & /@ llist, Last];
 brackets = data[[All, 1, 4]];
 If[MemberQ[brackets, #], , AppendTo[data, {{0, 0, 0, #}}]] & /@ 
  Range[Max[brackets]];
 BarChart[Sort[data, #1[[1, -1]] < #2[[1, -1]] &][[All, All, 3]], 
  ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
 ]` (quick and dirty & different to @anon's, is this what you want?)

Comment: @PinguinDirk I made a mistake, I meant to build one like yours :)

Comment: @PinguinDirk yes this is exactly what I am looking for. I updated the question with a screenshot of the output of your solution. How can we get the question off hold so you can answer the question as an actual answer?

Comment: Thanks for your answers @Anon and PinguinDirk. I'm still learning my way around stackexchange (especially how to state clear questions) and you've been a great help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an alternative way to create the chart that Pinguin Dirk created:

```
rules = #[[2]] -> #[[3]] & /@ {{1, 6, 611}, {2, 57, 732}, {3, 5, 
     526}, {4, 91, 72}, {5, 45, 583}, {6, 98, 552}, {7, 16, 981}, {8, 
     54, 439}, {9, 80, 804}, {10, 9, 633}};
bins = BinLists[rules[[All, 1]], 10] /. rules /. {} -> {0}
BarChart[bins, ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

Another way:

```
bins = Table[Select[list, i - 10 < #[[2]] <= i &], {i, 10, 100, 10}];
BarChart[bins /. {y : {_, _, x_} /; Depth[y] == 2 :> x, {} -> {0}}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

Comment: I like `BinLists`! +1

Answer (score 6):

You can use the ChartLayout option with value "Stacked".

```
d1 = Range@10; 
d2 = 4 + Range@10;
d3 = 6 + Range@10;

BarChart[Transpose[{d1, d2, d3}], ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

Comment: Can you explain how it is related to the question and the chart OP has posted, I'm still confused :/

Comment: @Kuba I agree that the OP would get a more complete answer if they clarified better how they wish to partition their data. But in the absence of that clarification, my answer is offered in the hope that if a stacked bar chart is what they need, then they will find this a useful element to their solution.

Comment: Ah, I thought you have a good interpretationto share :) but I find this answer useful. The problem is I really doubt if OP is looking for stacked bar chart. It rather looks like some sort of ColorFunction is what he need. We will see... maybe ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my idea from the comments, certainly with room for improvement.

```
Module[{data, brackets}, 
   data = GatherBy[Append[#, #[[2]]/10 // IntegerPart] & /@ llist, Last]; 
   brackets = data[[All, 1, 4]]; 
   If[MemberQ[brackets, #], , AppendTo[data, {{0, 0, 0, #}}]] & /@ Range[Max[brackets]]; 
   BarChart[Sort[data, #1[[1, -1]] < #2[[1, -1]] &][[All, All, 3]], 
       ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]]
```

I am using `GatherBy` to get the bins/brackets, opposed to `BinLists` in Anon's answer. I chose this approach as at first, I didn't notice you wanted to show the "empty" bins as well. In that case (not showing empty bins), the code can be simplified substantially, to something like:

```
BarChart[
   Sort[
      GatherBy[Append[#, #[[2]]/10 // IntegerPart] & /@ llist, Last], 
   #1[[1, -1]] < #2[[1, -1]] &][[All, All, 3]], 
   ChartLayout -> "Stacked"]
```

But admittedly, Anon's answer still is nicer :).